# Enterprise Territory Management without Sales Cloud User License

Tags: lightning, permissions, licenses, territory-management, territory

Is it possible to setup Enterprise Territory Management without Sales Cloud User licenses effectively? What are the downsides?

We currently only have Service Cloud User Licenses but have enabled Enterprise Territory Management in a sandbox and have been able to assign these users to the different territories.

Will there be functionality that is limited to these users due to the license that they have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to setup Enterprise Territory Management without Sales
>   Cloud User licenses effectively?

Yes, I implemented Enterprise territory Management with purely only Service Cloud User Licenses and there was no functionality limitations. Reports, List views, Territory Assignment, User Assignment, Manual Account Assignment all worked as expected per the implementation guide documentation.