# True differences between Sales Cloud and Service Cloud licenses?

Tags: servicecloud, licenses, sales-cloud, userlicense

Finding the difference in features between Sales Cloud and Service Cloud licenses has been quite challenging and the documentation seems to be misleading. I have been able to determine that both have access to:

- Accounts, Campaigns, Leads, Opportunities, Cases, Contracts (while the documentation would seem to suggest otherwise)
- [This question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/291585/enterprise-territory-management-without-sales-cloud-user-license) seems to suggest that Territory Management can work for service users as well

On the other hand I was able to see that you do seem to need a Service Cloud license for at least:

- Entitlements
- Service Contracts

Is there a definitive list of what cannot be made available in Sales Cloud to a Service Cloud user and vice-versa?

Comment: Might help you. 
Sales cloud: https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/pricing/DS_SalesCloud_EdCompare.pdf

Service Cloud: https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/pricing/salesforce-service-cloud-pricing-editions.pdf

Comment: This doesn't really cover what is available to *only* available to those license types and it's really more high level. For example, service cloud users can access almost all of the Sales Cloud features (like contracts) even though they are not listed on that document

Comment: Another example is that in those sheets, Lightning Sync is listed only under Sales Cloud but is available with either license

Comment: your best bet will be to talk to an/your Account Executive. Tushar listed official docs that go into some detail you're looking for (and a disclaimer it may not be error-free). Yes, both share some of the common CRM objects - Sales Cloud has the case object and Service Cloud has leads/opps/contacts - but, it's really just the object/schema without many of the features a lot will want given those objects (ex. Sales has quotes, splits, forecasting & Service has service console, knowledge). Not to mention the confusion where there's editions, licenses, add-ons, etc.

Comment: Even object access without respect to functionality would be helpful - that is also quite fuzzy

Comment: do you already have a started list (ex I see you mentioned a couple unique to Service Cloud)? It's possible we could make a community wiki answer that anyone could edit. That wouldn't really be canonical, but it could be a good resource